# Why can't we use integer precision in printf in java? Just curious

Tags: java, printf

```
System.out.printf("%.2d",123);
```

it seems logical to get the output of 12 or 23 but why they chose to make this an error instead?

Comment: precision is generally about the numbers after the decimal point. ints/integers don't have a decimal point

Comment: Exceptions bring the developer's attention to likely programming errors, instead of quietly accepting them. If I've used the wrong format specifier, I want to know so I can fix it; I don't want the method to guess what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

> ... it seems logical to get the output of 12 or 23 ...

No.  Sorry.  Mistake. Incorrect thinking.

The `printf` method behaves according to what its specification says, not what "seems to be logical" to you<sup>1</sup>.

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) says this:

> "The format specifiers for general, character, and numeric types have the following syntax:
>
> ```
>  %[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
> ```
>
> The optional precision is a non-negative decimal integer usually used to restrict the number of characters. *The specific behavior depends on the conversion.*
>
> **Byte, Short, Integer, and Long**
>
> [For all conversions ...]
>
> *The precision is not applicable*. If precision is specified then an `IllegalFormatPrecisionException` will be thrown."

Further reading of the javadocs for `Formatter` reveal that `%d` formats do not support "truncation" of the digits of an integer.

> ... why they chose to make this an error instead?

Because a clear runtime error telling you that there is a mistake in you code is better than the application producing unexpected results which might slip past your testing and other quality control processes.

---

<sup>1 - In my opinion, what you are suggesting is counter-intuitive not logical.   So whose "logical" should win?  Neither!  You are supposed to read the spec rather than assuming that everything works like you think it should work.  Note that this principle applies to all programming activities.  When in doubt, read the spec!</sup>